# Android's equivalent to CoreText

Tags: android, ios, android-widget, core-text

We have an App for iOS that renders an enormous amount of text: http://itunes.apple.com/br/app/biblia-sagrada/id370178518?mt=8

We use CoreText to render text and give the user the ability to change formatting, font-size and font face.

We are trying to port it to Android but I'm not sure if there's a substitute for CoreText in Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent to iOS' CoreText in Android is the `drawText` APIs, part of the Canvas class,  `Canvas.drawText()`, `Canvas.drawPosText()`, etc. see [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for Canvas for more detail. These graphics APIs use [Skia](http://code.google.com/p/skia/) underneath.

The functionalities that these graphics APIs provide are not the same as those in iOS, say there's no `CTFramesetter` equivalent that helps you layout text and handle line breaks for you. With the `drawText` APIs, you can only draw one line at a time, you will have to handle line breaks yourself, It is like using `CTTypesetter` in iOS. For laying out text, see `Paint.breakText` and `Paint.measureText`.

For changing font size & font face, you can set related attributes in the `Paint` object, which is passed as the last parameter to the `drawText` APIs.

Snippet:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setTextSize(14);
String text = "Hello world!";
canvas.drawText(text, 0, 100, paint);
```

Note: The coordinate system used in the Android `drawText` APIs is from `left-top` corner.

Comment: Has anything changed in the last 6 years?  Has Android now got a real text system?

Comment: @Lothar, I haven't worked on text rendering for a long time. But I guess the answer to your question is still no, I didn't see any significant changes regarding text rendering introduced in the past years. Since the performance of `WebView` as well as that of the hardware has been improved a lot, HTML for complex text laying-out/rendering may be the way to go nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

`TextView` can handle "the ability to change formatting, font-size and font face", via spannable strings. See the `android.text.style` package for the various effects that you can apply.

In terms of "enormous amounts of text", wrap the `TextView` in a `ScrollView`.

You can always fall back to using `WebView`, which gives you full WebKit capabilities to render HTML, if needed.

Comment: On iOS, CoreText tells the exact amount of text that would be visible on a certain frame. This feature is very, as the application can place several frames placed on a ScrollView, paginating the text. Could TextView do the same on Android?

Comment: @javsmo: Not that I am aware of. The only paginated text I have seen on Android is with ebook readers, which will use HTML and `WebView`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, not really, most ebook readers use canvas and the drawText APIs, I once implemented an ebook reader, things would be much more controllable with the drawText APIs.